# Why am i getting the error cannot read property data of undefined in vue

Tags: vue.js

In vue, I have an array passed in from a parent component. I have some default values set to populate the form, however, I want to insert the 'application_id' into one of the defaults. the code below brings back the error 'Error in data(): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined"'

If i print 'this.data[0]['application_id']' on the page it brings back the value i want fine. not sure why data is undefined below?

```
props: {
        data: Array,        
    },
```

```
data:() =>({
        educationDetails: [],
        defaults:{
            application_id:this.data[0]['application_id'],
        }
    }),
```

Comment: if you `console.log(this.data)` inside `data()` do you see your values ? also try to not change `application_id` so there will be no reference update

Comment: also if your `data` props is loaded by an API or other methods that takes time you will always have this issue, the solution is to only mount the component when `data` is loaded and not empty

Comment: The arrow function probably causes issues here.
Try the exact same but use `data() { return { ... } }` instead.
See this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-bush-gb7fq)